# Не получается обрабатывать два события в pyrogram

Tags: python, asyncio, pyrogram

пишу бота для телеграмм с использованием pyrogram. Нужно сделать рассылку по чатам по айди, что я и сделал:

```
async def start_mailing():
    while True:
        if check_time(settings['timer']): # Нужно отправлять сообщения по таймеру
            print('Sending...')
            for chat_ids in settings['ids']:
                await app.send_message(chat_ids, settings['text'])
                sleep(INTERVAL)
            new_timer = []
            for i in settings['timer']:
                new_timer.append(update_time(i, 7))
            update_settings('timer', new_timer)
        sleep(0.5)
```

И эта функция работает. Но как только я добавляю handler для обработки сообщений, то он не работает:

```
@app.on_message()
async def message_handler(client: Client, message: Message):
    print(message.text)
```

Запуск кода:

```
async def main():
    await start_mailing()

app.run(main())
```

То есть рассылка работает, но бот никак не реагирует на входящие сообщения. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Весь код:

```
from time import sleep

from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.types import Message

from src.utils import *

CFG = get_cfg()

api_id = CFG['api_id']
api_hash = CFG['api_hash']

INTERVAL = 0.5

settings = get_settings()
app = Client(CFG['username'], CFG['api_id'], CFG['api_hash'])


@app.on_message()
async def message_handler(client: Client, message: Message):
    print(message.text)


async def start_mailing():
    while True:
        if check_time(settings['timer']):
            print('Sending...')
            for chat_ids in settings['ids']:
                await app.send_message(chat_ids, settings['text'])
                sleep(INTERVAL)
            new_timer = []
            for i in settings['timer']:
                new_timer.append(update_time(i, 7))
            update_settings('timer', new_timer)
        sleep(0.5)


async def main():
    await start_mailing()


app.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, вероятно, в том, что вы запускаете бесконечный цикл `start_mailing()` перед запуском бота с помощью `app.run(main())`, и программа не достигает строки с запуском обработчика сообщений `@app.on_message()`.

Вместо этого, вы можете запустить `start_mailing()` и `app.run(main())` в разных асинхронных задачах и дождаться их завершения. Попробуйте следующий подход:

```py
async def main():
    mailing_task = asyncio.create_task(start_mailing())
    await app.start()
    await mailing_task

async def run_bot():
    await app.run(main())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_bot())
```

Таким образом, сначала запускается бесконечный цикл рассылки `start_mailing()` в отдельной асинхронной задаче, а затем запускается бот через `app.run(main())`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоил писать не отдельный ответ, а дополнить предыдущий.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант.
Проблема, вероятно, заключается в том, что вы запускаете основной цикл приложения `app.run(main())`, который начинает выполнение `start_mailing()` и затем блокирует выполнение дальше. Это происходит из-за бесконечного цикла `while True` внутри `start_mailing()`. В результате обработчик сообщений `message_handler` никогда не вызывается, потому что выполнение остается в `start_mailing()`.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно запускать `start_mailing()` и `app.run(main())` в разных корутинах. Вот как можно сделать это:

```py
import asyncio
from time import sleep
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.types import Message
from src.utils import get_cfg, get_settings, check_time, update_settings, update_time

CFG = get_cfg()
api_id = CFG['api_id']
api_hash = CFG['api_hash']
INTERVAL = 0.5
settings = get_settings()
app = Client(CFG['username'], CFG['api_id'], CFG['api_hash'])

@app.on_message()
async def message_handler(client: Client, message: Message):
    print(message.text)

async def start_mailing():
    while True:
        if check_time(settings['timer']):
            print('Sending...')
            for chat_ids in settings['ids']:
                await app.send_message(chat_ids, settings['text'])
                await asyncio.sleep(INTERVAL)
            new_timer = []
            for i in settings['timer']:
                new_timer.append(update_time(i, 7))
            update_settings('timer', new_timer)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        start_mailing(),
        app.run()
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

Теперь обе функции `start_mailing()` и `app.run()` запускаются параллельно, и ваш обработчик сообщений должен быть вызван при получении нового сообщения.

Comment: Я столкнулся с точно такой же проблемоц, ищу ответ, вот выше возможные ворианты решения, которые мне удалось найти...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)